# ¿cómo validar un checkbox en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

En mi archivo de migracion creado en laravel tengo varios datos para validar nombre, teléfono y un checkbox

En la migración puse así $table->boolean('acepto'); en el metodo store de mi controlador resourse tengo $datosusuario->acepto = $request->acepto; pero al rellenar el formulario me lanza el siguiente error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'acepto' for column 'acepto' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `cursos` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `plan`, `acepto`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ejemplo ejemplo, oferta@gmail.com, +527731112324, Plan mensual, acepto, 2020-12-12 04:26:09, 2020-12-12 04:26:09))

En mi tabla tengo todos las mismas columnas y los name coniciden.

Comment: El valor para la columna booleana puede ser 0 o 1, no un string.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL no tiene un tipo booleano incorporado. Sin embargo, usa TINYINT(1) en su lugar . Para hacerlo más conveniente, MySQL proporciona BOOLEAN o BOOLcomo sinónimo de TINYINT(1).

En MySQL, 0 se considera falso y 1 se considera verdadero.
Podrías utilizar tambiém  literales booleanos, TRUE y FALSE eso evalúa a 1 y 0 respectivamente.

cualquier cosa distinta, dará error siempre.

Comment: Gracias por la información.

Answer (score 0):

El checkbox te esta enviando un valor text porque a lo mejor en acepto le mandas el value=acepto, deberia ser value=1, puede cambiarlo o poner un ternario cuando creas el modelo asi

```
  $datosusuario->acepto = $request->acepto=='acepto'?1:0;
```